# Alpha 2.8 - Mirror in edit mode

Tags: mirror, subdivision-surface, experimental-features

I'm currently discovering the reworked UI of Blender 2.8. I have some kind of cube, cut in half, mirrored to a full cube again using the mirror modifier. In edit mode, I've noticed some changes that I personally dislike.

It could be a bug, a feature, or just a default setting:
I'm only seeing the half mesh that I'm able to edit, the other side is simply not shown. In previous blender versions, you could always see the mirrored part, here it is completely gone.

Also, if I'm using subdivision surface, I can only see the real model in edit mode, without the filter "applied".

Here are two screenshots showing a similar model in edit mode:

[image: How editing the mesh should look]

[image: How it actually looks like]

Do you know if this is just a simple setting?

Thanks

Comment: At this point version 2.8 is still under development, many things are missing, or not implemented or will move around in the interface. This might be one of the many pieces that are changing

Comment: I'm aware this is all subject to change. But maybe I'm just missing a small setting.

Comment: My advice is that you stick to the current release version of blender for modelling and try 2.8 for materials and render engine only. 2.8 is not even in beta stage yet.

Comment: Yeah that's probably the best thing to do. I don't do any serious work right now, just messing around. I've changed the title, because Beta is misleading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an experimental  version of blender that is still incomplete and evolving constantly.

Comment: But maybe it is just a setting I'm not aware of and someone knows a simple answer. Does it really hurt to have a topic about an upcoming release?

Comment: To me as another common user, 2.8 seems to be a very long slow process. I found this question due to having the same problem on alpha 2. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it's simply broken at the moment - the button on the modifier to 'Display modifier in Edit Mode' is still there, it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do right now.
I'm sure they'll get round to it eventually!